# How to design star schema in a restaurant scenario where customer place food orders and each order contains multiple food items

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling, data-warehouse, star-schema-datawarehouse

Here I am having a FACT table, **FACT_Orders** and which has fields **customer_id, order_id, total_cost, created_date, updated_date**.

Also I have one more FACT table, **FACT_Order_List** to keep the items in the order which has fields order_list_id, order_id, item_id

Also I have the dimension tables **DIM_Item** and **DIM_Customer** to keep the arrtibutes of Item and Customer

From the FACT tables, I need to compute the most popular item and least popular item sold

Is this good design having two FACT tables and joining FACT tables for the computations?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would make the question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that :

> An item has many orders and an order contains many items.

you can have a fact record like below : CustomerId=5 ordered 2 items

```
OrderId OrderListId ItemId CustomerId ItemPrice   TotalCost   CreatedDate
1       1           12     5          100         350         17-01-2021
1       1           15     5          250         350         17-01-2021
```

You don't join fact tables. Facts are combined by summarizing each set of measures individually by common dimensions then joining the summarized sets on those dimensions.

Your model can be like below:

[image]

> Regading the  updated_date in the fact :

Fact tables should not be updated. There are several really good reasons why facts measure values should almost never be updated. ... Fact Table Processing: Preforming updates on tables can be a very costly operation on the SQL Server data warehouse database server! Fact tables can and should be very large.